# The use of the word "recuperating" in context

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Tell me please if the word is used correctly in the sentence.

> **Recuperating** exercises is an essential part of recovery from musculoskeletal injuries.

What I am trying to communicate is that the exercises that help someone to recuperate is an essential part of recovery. What is the best word to communicate the meaning? Perhaps the word *recovery* before the word *exercise* suits the best.

Comment: You already mention recovery in the second part of your sentence, so it seems redundant to mention it in the first part too. I would simply say *exercise is essential in the recovery from musculoskeletal injuries*. (In that sentence, *exercise* is a mass noun, so it's singular. If you really want to use the plural, you need to say *exercises* ***are***, not ***is***.)

Comment: What if there weren't the part with "recovery". Is it correct to say: "Recuperating exercises is important for future performence"?

Comment: Perhaps if you are stressing a specific *type* of exercise. I'm not sure if I'd use *recuperating*, however. I might use *recuperation*. (When I hear *recuperating exercises*, even though I know *recuperating* being used as a gerund rather than the present participle, I keep thinking it's the exercises themselves that are recuperating.) Again, it should either be *the recuperation exercise* ***is*** or *recuperation exercises* ***are***.